# Angularjs $http request waits till the previous request is completed

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I'm sending a request which takes little long to respond at the same time am also sending another request which is completely independent from the first one but the second request is processed only when the first one is completed. Even route change shows pending until the first request is completed

Please help me solve this.

Comment: You need to tell what you tried. Without seeing code, it is too hard to understand your problem.

Comment: Please show your code -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This seems like a limitation on the server-side. AngularJS does HTTP requests in parallel by default.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to send the second request into the callback of the first one.

For example:

```
// First GET Request:
$http.get('/firstUrl').then(function(response) {
    // Start second request after the first is finished.
    return $http.get('/secondUrl');
}).then(function(response) {
    // Change route or something else with the second response
    console.log(response);
});
```

In this way the second request can start only when the first is completed and you can also handle the response object obtained by the first request before start the other one.